# Check statement for every list item

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a const `experience` value, `person` object, list of `skill` and method (can not modify it) `hasSkill(skill,person,experience)` which returns boolean.
I want to check that `person` has every skill from the list.

My code is:

```
int experience = 5;

private hasAllSkills(person){
return skillList.stream().filter(s -> hasSingleSkill(s,person)).collect(Collectors.toList()).size() == skillList.size() ? true : false;
}

private boolean hasSingleSkill(Skill s, Person p){
return hasSkill(s,p,experience);
}
```

I am pretty sure that there is better solution but can not find it; what should I do to fix my code?

Comment: Well you can remove the `? true : false` for one thing... what do you think that conditional operator is achieving?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you want [`allMatch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#allMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-):

```
return skillList.stream().allMatch(s -> hasSingleSkill(s, person));
```

As another more general matter, any time you have

```
condition ? true : false
```

you can just replace that with

```
condition
```

So your existing code of

```
(long-expression).size() == skillList.size() ? true : false
```

could be simplified to

```
(long-expression).size() == skillList.size()
```

Comment: You can even go further and say *anytime* a `boolean` literal (`true` or `false`) appears in a compound expression, there is an alternative without literals (unless the result is always `true` or `false` anyway). In most cases, it will be simpler.